# $q and $http are executing infinite times even if call is made single time

Tags: angularjs, api, http, service, controller

I want to fetch and display rupee symbol in html page. UTF code is stored in databse. I wrote following code in constructor

```
vm.getCurrency = function(){
     console.log("abcde");
     ExpensedetailService.getcurrency(currency).then(function (result) {
     console.log("abcde"+result);
     return result;
  },function (error){
     console.log("Error is there");
});
}
```

vm is assigned with this.

and following code in service. I gave $http call in service but the call is going infinite types.

```
    function getcurrency(currency){

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log("currency "+ currency );
        $http.get('/api/staticdata?type='+currency).then(function(result) {
            if(result){
                //return result
                console.log(result);
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }
          },
          function (err) {
              deferred.reject(err);
          });

          return deferred.promise;
        }
```

It is fetching data from backend but not showing in html. and it is continuously executing in an infinite loop.
Console is printing as follows.
abcde
currency rupee
abcde
currency rupee
abcde
currency rupee
abcde
currency rupee
abcde
currency rupee
abcde
currency rupee
abcde

Comment: What is calling `vm.getCurrency`?

Comment: @MuliYulzary call is given in html as {{controlleAlias.getCurrency}}

Comment: That's a wrong way to do it, Angular is calling that function constantly because `{{}}` expressions are evaluated whenever something on the scope changes.
You need to do it through the controller and call it once, save the data and then use saved data as a scope variable afterwards. Also, a side note, you don't need the 'double promise' in the function, just return the whole `$http` request like this: `return $http.get(...)..../*your code*/;`

Comment: @AleksandarBencun is there any disadvantage of using double promise sir

Comment: Nope, just a side note on that one. Your issue is the one I have described above.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun thanks it stopped being repetitive

Answer (score 0):

Following OP's comment:

Using curly braces in templates is for **expressions** that need to be **watched** for changes constantly.
This causes the function to fire indefinitely.